# How to draw two non-concentric circles in CSS with numbers inside it?

Tags: html, css

I want to draw two circles, one inside the other with different centre point.
I then want to add a number inside each circle. How can I achieve this in HTML and CSS. I have attached the sample image of what I am looking for.

Why I am doing this is because I want to present the smaller circle as a part of bigger one to represent my data.

[image]

Comment: Try something first and post your code.

Comment: Tip: use a "div" and the rest are css, try styling the div to have round edges which makes it a circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution

```css
.green-circle {
  color: green;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.red-circle {
  color: red;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 15px;
}
.number {
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="green-circle">
  <div class="number">8</div>
  <div class="red-circle">
    <div class="number">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```